# Using result for sum of geometric series prove

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, geometric-series

$\frac{1}{(\alpha+e^{-x^2})}$ = ...

using the sum of the geometric series 
  $1 + z + z^{2}+...+z^{n}$

Any help on this would be very appreciated as I'm stuck as to where to start. As in the first fraction the denominator is not 1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start :

$1+z+z^2+...+z^{n-1}=\frac{1-z^{n}}{1-z}$ thus using $z=-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\alpha}$ you can write $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{z^k}+\frac{z^n}{1-z}=\frac{1}{1-z}$ replace $z$ and change the indices of the sum to make it start at $1$ and end at $n$...

Here is the solution :

> You will have $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{(-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\alpha})^k}+\frac{(-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\alpha})^n}{1-(-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\alpha})}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{(-1)^k\frac{e^{-kx^2}}{\alpha^k}}+(-1)^n\frac{e^{-nx^2}}{\alpha^n(\alpha+e^{-x^2})}=\frac{1}{\alpha+e^{-x^2}}$ then by changing the indices you have $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{(k-1)}\frac{e^{-(k-1)x^2}}{\alpha^{k-1}}}+(-1)^n\frac{e^{-nx^2}}{\alpha^n(\alpha+e^{-x^2})}=\frac{1}{\alpha+e^{-x^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Start from the high school identity
$$1-u^n=(1-u)(1+u+\dots+u^{n-1}),$$
and rewrite it as
$$\frac1{1-u}=1+u+\dots+u^{n-1}+\frac{u^n}{1-u}.$$